# What does it mean that "you cannot suspend an inner coroutine that was called within an outer coroutine without suspending the outer coroutine"?

Tags: c++, stack, c++20, c++-coroutine

This is a quote from Josuttis' "C++20 - The Complete Guide":

> - Coroutines are stackless. You cannot suspend an inner coroutine that was called within an outer coroutine without suspending the outer coroutine. You can only suspend the outer coroutine as a whole.

And this is before any snippet of code is shown at all, at the very beginning of chapter 14.

What does that mean?

I understand that a coroutine suspends at suspension points, so it's suspensions (and the whole fact that it is a coroutine rather than an ordinary function) happens at specific points, those where `co_await`/`co_yield`/`co_return` are used. To me this means that it is the coroutine that "decides" when to suspend. Yes, whether the suspension truly happens, and what the interface makes available to the caller depends not just on the body of the coroutine but also on its interface, i.e. the return type. But to me its still not the caller to decide the suspension. Quite the opposite the caller is the one that decides whether the coroutine should be resumed.

I don't even understand if I interpret it as "an inner coroutine .... cannot suspend itself without suspending the outer coroutine", because it's clearly possible (and there are examples showing it in the book itself) that a coroutine `f` calls another coroutine `g` and keeps resuming `g` until `g` is done, at which point `f` continues, with the control that has never gone back to `f`'s caller yet.

So that's why I don't understand what the quoted text means. Furthermore, even the beginning of the quote

> Coroutines are stackless

is unclear to me with respect to the rest of it.

Comment: Sounds confusing and wrong indeed, and that's not what stackless coroutines mean at all. A copy of the book I found online has a entirely different quote.

Comment: @tkausl, what's the version reported on page ii? I have the paper version, which reports 2022-10-30, just like the most recent online version [here](https://leanpub.com/cpp20).

Comment: First Edition, published 2021-12-31.

Comment: @Enlico: Given the number of questions you've asked about this book, maybe you should just stop reading it. It would also help to know some context around this quote.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm not sure I understand if your suggestion to give up implies a judgement on the writer or on the reader. But I think it does imply at least one of the two. And I have the feeling I will not be made aware of it, right?

Comment: @Enlico: I don't expect a book about C++20 as a whole to explain every detail of coroutines. But when it gets basic facts about them *this wrong*/confusing, it's time to put the book down.

Answer (score 0):

That C++ coroutines are stackless simply means that their local variables and “return” addresses do not live on the ordinary **function call stack** but on the heap (modulo optimization).  This gives additional flexibility: a stackful coroutine (*e.g.*, as implemented by `swapcontext` from old versions of POSIX) can obviously not be resumed by another (user) thread, nor can it survive the function that called it.

The rest of the description seems to be trying to describe the concomitant **restriction** on stackless coroutines: while a suspension of a stackful coroutine is by necessity a suspension of its entire (user) thread, such that any stackful coroutine can (only) suspend itself and all its callers together, the suspension of a stackless coroutine has no direct effect on its caller (except perhaps for user-mode scheduling performed alongside the suspension).  It is common for the caller to suspend in response to the suspension of the callee—this is the typical function of `co_await`—but it must be explicit.  In particular, this means that no generic **wrapper** function written without awareness of coroutines can be suspended at all, which can be an impediment to adopting coroutines but can benefit reading them.

I believe that the quote is **meant** to say “You cannot suspend [an operation from within] an inner coroutine that was called within an outer coroutine without [explicitly also] suspending the outer coroutine.”, but as written it does seem to be a better description of the stackful case (except that “without suspending the whole thread” would make more sense there), so it’s possible that it’s merely missing a segue.